# Broken PDO Insert during while loop

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to put together a simple php page to monitor my server. It downloads an XML, parses it during a while loop and then inserts a new row for each result. There are six records in the video_servers table, and the SELECT part is working great, till I try inserting the results, then it only loops through one time. If I take out the `try` INSERT portion, it will loop through the six times printing the var_dump. What am I missing on this? The insert works just fine once, then ends.

```
try {
    $query = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM video_servers");
    $query->bindValue(':url', $url, PDO::PARAM_STR);  
    $query->bindValue(':title', $server, PDO::PARAM_STR); 
    $query->bindValue(':type', $type, PDO::PARAM_STR); 
    $query->execute();
}
catch (PDOException $e){
  printf("something broke");// logError($e->getMessage(), $query->queryString, __FILE__, __LINE__ );
   exit;
}


while($results = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    $xmlfile = simplexml_load_file('http://lalalala.com/connectioncounts');
    $count = $xmlfile->ConnectionsCurrent;
    $server = $results['title'];
    $type = "active-connections";



    try {
    $query = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO dashboardserverstats (server, type, value) VALUES (:server, :type, :value)");
    $query->bindValue(':server', $server, PDO::PARAM_STR);  
    $query->bindValue(':type', $type, PDO::PARAM_STR); 
    $query->bindValue(':value', $count, PDO::PARAM_STR); 
    $query->execute();
    }
    catch (PDOException $e){
      echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }
var_dump($results);
}
```

Comment: You only need to `prepare` the statement once. You can also move the `bind` statements outside the while loop and use `bindParam` instead of `bindValue`...and the reason it is failing is because of @iCode4U answer, you are overwriting the `$query` var, it's in your while condition, then you override it in the try block

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the second query change the name of the variable $query. you are overwriting it.